# The usage of “ is of ”

Tags: grammar

Here are some examples:

The far side of the Moon **is of** particular interest to the scientists.

Anglo **is of** European origin

Morning exercises **is of** benefit to your health

So what does "is of" in these sentences mean?

Comment: What is "is"?  What is a "preposition"?

Comment: I believe this question has already been answered [HERE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/137863/what-is-meaning-of-is-of).

Comment: And [HERE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/254847/the-usage-of-is-of)

Comment: [of interest](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20interest) [of benefit to](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20benefit%20to)

Answer (score 2):

*is of* does not have a meaning. It is not a constituent of any sentence, but just a couple of words that happen to come together.

In all your three sentences, the verb is the copula *is*, and the complement is a phrase beginning with *of.* In each case this is "of" expressing a property or quality.

Answer (score 0):

It’s tough to explain what “is of” generally means, but I can reword these sentences for you so they will hopefully make more sense.

1. The dark side of the moon is particularly interesting to the scientists.
2. Anglo originates from Europe.
3. Morning exercises are beneficial to your health.